# wp_mail not sending email on custom function

Tags: email, phpmailer

I have updated my wordpress to the new 5.7 version, I have a function in my functions.php file to send an email.

The thing is, i have used this function before and it all worked well. Now after upgrading, i am unable send email from my custom function send_email()

Custom email function in functions.php

```
 function send_email(){
        $from = "Admin <no-reply@lamza.co.za>";
        $to = "testing@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Lamza Activation";
        $activationEmail = '';
        $headers = "From:" . $from . PHP_EOL;
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $activationEmail, $headers);
    }
```

I keep getting false value.

I am able to send test email using Easy WP SMTP but I can not on my function.

I need to know what I need to change, configurations or is it my human error.

Thanks yall

Comment: Can you see any errors in your logs? It's probably worth also implementing the [wp_mail_failed](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_failed/) hook or temporarily adding an extra log to the two places it's called in wp-includes/pluggable.php.

Comment: I think you're also missing the From line from $headers: you're overwriting the value with the content type not adding to it.

Comment: [Here's two example wp_mail_failed handlers.](https://gist.github.com/RupW/7ef75c22e88dff18e632eb6676635bd0)

Comment: I added the functions to my functions.php and i am not getting any errors.

Before posting this question, i got this error but now i can not reproduce this error display

WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [wp_mail_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid address:  (From): wordpress@localhost

Comment: Yes, wordpress@localhost is the default if you don't set a from address. Your `$headers = "From:" . $from . PHP_EOL;` value is getting lost because you're overwriting $headers with an array that just contains the Content-Type.

Comment: I hard coded the values into wp_mail, still i get an 500 internal sever error wp_mail("testemail@gmail.com", "We did it", "We done did it once again POI lets win", "From: <info@lemza.co.za>");

Comment: Hi Rup,My wordpress had been referencing the wrong folder in the plugable.php file in wp-includes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The way you're applying the headers is incorrect.  You set a "from" address in the headers as a string, and then you immediately overwrite that with an array (so the "from" address is lost). (You're also setting the $from address twice)

Try it this way:

```
function send_email(){
   $to = $email;
   $subject = "Lamza Activation";
   $activationEmail = '';
   $from = "testing <no-reply@lamza.co.za>";
   $headers[] = "From:" . $from . PHP_EOL;
   $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
   wp_mail($to, $subject, $activationEmail, $headers);
}
```

OR, you could also use the `wp_mail` filters to set the from address and content type instead.

```
function send_email(){
   $to = $email;
   $subject = "Lamza Activation";
   $activationEmail = '';
   wp_mail($to, $subject, $activationEmail);
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', function( $from ) {
     return "no-reply@lamza.co.za";
});

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', function( $from_name ) {
     return "testing";
});

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type {
     return 'text/html';
});

// This one you may not need as WP defaults to UTF-8...
add_filter( 'wp_mail_charset', function( $charset ) {
     return 'UTF-8';
});
```

Comment: I did exactly this and still nothing, I enabled all the error reporting settings but still no errors being displayed. 

Everytime the wp_mail function fires, the website crashes. My code is a copy and paste from an old project which worked perfectly, now for some odd reason wp_mail is crashing and tried most settings, even deleted my code and replaced it with code from wordpress directly

Comment: My wordpress had been referencing the wrong folder in the plugable.php file in wp-includes.

Thank you